# Java JDBC: MySQLNonTransientConnectionException when trying to connect with IP address

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

If I do this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/imageusers?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&relaxAutoCommit=true", "username", "password");
```

then it works perfectly fine but if I do this:

```
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/imageusers?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&relaxAutoCommit=true", "username", "password");
```

Then it gives me a long list of errors:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I got my IP address from this website: http://whatismyipaddress.com/
and double checked it on another finder and it was the same so I don't think I'm putting in the IP address wrong. I also have made an exception for the port 3306 in windows firewall and have checked to see if MySQL was running in the services application in windows and it was. I had the MySQL program thing open and running as well. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are giving here is public IP. It won't convert it to a private ip address. Try pinging to the public IP from the machine you are connecting to the DB server. It also won't work. I suggest you using a private ip address.

Comment: yes I used the private IP address I got from the command prompt by using ipconfig and it follows 192.168....etc. it works now, but is this accessible from the internet? How can I make it so that I can do this from another computer?

Comment: Give it a domain name and add a dns entry.

Comment: can you link me a tutorial on how to do that? thanks.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please mark it as the answer too.